# CSS - Rectangle div with cut corners and border color

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to achieve the shape as shown in this image:
To have 2 rectangle divs with cut corners , and 1 div positioned behind another div.

[image]

But the corners seems incorrect and I can't find the way to show the borders of the shapes.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.connect {
  width: 254px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  background: #FF2D5069;
  border-top: 2px solid #FF2175;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.connect::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -2px;
  border-top: 52px solid white;
  border-left: 42px solid transparent;
}

.connect::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -2px;
  border-top: 52px solid white;
  border-right: 42px solid transparent;
}

.connect-behind {
  width: 300px;
  height: 44px;
  background: red;
  background: #FF2D5069;
  border-top: 2px solid #FF2175;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.connect-behind::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -2px;
  border-top: 46px solid white;
  border-left: 26px solid transparent;
}

.connect-behind::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -2px;
  border-top: 46px solid white;
  border-right: 26px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="connect"></div>
    <div class="connect-behind"></div>
  </div>
```

I took reference from other threads to use `behind` and `after` for the solution but it doesn't seem working correct for my problem. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Why not use something like SVG ?

Answer (score 6):

You could use perspective and transform:

possible example *(for infos : with grid instead absolute)* :

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: end;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 50px;
}

.connect,
.connect-behind {
  transform: rotatex(50deg);
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FF2D5069;
  border-top: 2px solid #FF2175;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}

.connect-behind {
  width: 300px;
  height: 44px;
}

.connect {
  width: 254px;
  height: 50px;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="connect"></div>
  <div class="connect-behind"></div>
</div>
```

**to draw a `border` around the shape, `drop-shadow` could be usefull**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: end;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 50px;
   filter:
   drop-shadow( 1px  0px 0 )
   drop-shadow(-1px  0px 0 )
   drop-shadow( 0px  1px 0 )
   drop-shadow( 0px -1px 0 );
}

.connect,
.connect-behind {
  transform: rotatex(50deg);
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:white;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  transform-origin: bottom center; 
  background:#ffa500;
}

.connect-behind {
  width: 254px;
  height: 50px; 
  border-left:solid 2px;
  border-right:solid 2px;
}

.connect {
  background:#ed1c24;
  width: 300px;
  height: 44px;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="connect"></div>
  <div class="connect-behind"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do I add border color to the shape

Comment: @hatched you can set the border to the lements themselves . or is it a border only around the shape that you need ?

Comment: is to the shape itself. Thanks for the solution, working great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use clip-path for things like this. Works well in a ( I think ) most browsers. Some, like ie11 and older browsers won't render it correctly, though, so you may need a fallback for those cases.

```css
body {
overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.connect {
  width: 254px;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  background: #FF2D5069;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.connect-border-left {
    height: 80px;
    width: 2px;
    background: black;
    left: calc(50% - 131px);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12px;
    transform: rotate(34deg) translateX(-50%);
    display: inline-block;
}

.connect-border-right {
    height: 80px;
    width: 2px;
    background: black;
    right: calc(50% - 131px);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12px;
    transform: rotate(-34deg) translateX(-50%);
    display: inline-block;
}


.connect-behind {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  background: #FF2D5069;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(14% 0%, 86% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.connect-behind-border-right {
    height: 100px;
    width: 2px;
    background: black;
    right: calc(50% - 103px);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -11px;
    transform: rotate(-32deg) translateX(-50%);
    display: inline-block;
}

.connect-behind-border-left {
    height: 100px;
    width: 2px;
    background: black;
    left: calc(50% - 103px);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -11px;
    transform: rotate(32deg) translateX(-50%);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="connect"></div>
    <div class="connect-border-left"></div>
    <div class="connect-border-right"></div>
    <div class="connect-behind"></div>
    <div class="connect-behind-border-left"></div>
    <div class="connect-behind-border-right"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: any ways to also add the black color border to the side ?

Comment: Yeah you can just use other divs and position them correctly on either side of the item. Clipped items like those polygons don't allow for borders on the sides since their original shape is a square or rectangle, so the borders don't show up properly.

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution. Working very fine.

Answer (score 1):

an idea with skew transformation, clip-path and multiple background:

```css
.box {
  --b:3px;   /* border width */
  --t:20px; /* top part width */
  --s:30px; /* side part width */
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:250px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before,
.box::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:50%;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:var(--b) 0 0 var(--b);
  background:
    linear-gradient(black 0 0) 0 var(--t)/100% var(--b),
    linear-gradient(black 0 0) var(--s) 0/var(--b) 100%,
    linear-gradient(red 0 0)  left/var(--s) 100%, 
    orange;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform-origin:bottom right;
  transform:skew(-20deg);
  clip-path:polygon(0 calc(var(--t) + var(--b)), calc(var(--s) + var(--b)) calc(var(--t) + var(--b)),calc(var(--s) + var(--b)) 0,60% 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
}
.box::after {
  transform:scale(-1,1) skew(-20deg);
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--b:2px;--t:30px;--s:15px;"></div>
```